# How to pass params from one action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to pass all the params of one action to another, is this possibe?

```
def action1
  billing_id = params["billing_id"]
  # many more param values here....

  perform_transaction(billing_id)
end

def action2
  if params["hello"].nil?
    return action1
  end
  ...
end
```

Is it possible for me to somehow pass all the params when I call

```
return action1
```

I am calling the 1st action from the 2nd action, and I need all the param values passes also.

Comment: for a request, `params` will be available in `action1` by default (when called from `action2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params will be available to all the actions in your controller by default.

Update:

You can learn more about how `params` end up in controller actions from the following link:
https://medium.com/launch-school/params-in-rails-where-do-they-come-from-b172cdb46eb4

Answer (score 0):

All action methods in a Rails controller have access to all the params.